# HowTo create a hash index in ArangoDB via its HTTP API

Tags: rest, http, arangodb

I'm trying to create a hash index in ArangoDB via its HTTP API via CURL.

Within my ArangoDB I have several databases like:

- production
- staging
- test

As mentioned in the docs in https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/http/indexes/persistent/ one should call the "Index API" with an URL scheme as follows:

- `http://localhost:8529/_api/index?collection=products`

Applied to my use case I have the following URL:

- `http://localhost:8529/_api/index?colletion=NodesElectric`

Executing the CURL command always returns with an error like:

```
{  
  "error": true,
  "errorMessage": "collection or view not found",
  "code": 404,
  "errorNum": 1203
}
```

I suppose that the problem is caused by having the collection "NodesElectric" in all databases "production", "staging",...

My question is how do I specify the according database for the mentioned collection?

Have not found an hint in the docs herein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any operation triggered via ArangoDB's HTTP REST API is executed in the context
> of exactly one database. To explicitly specify the database in a
> request, the request URI must contain the database name in front of
> the actual path:
>
> http://localhost:8529/_db/mydb/... where ... is the actual path to the
> accessed resource. In the example, the resource will be accessed in
> the context of the database mydb. Actual URLs in the context of mydb
> could look like this:
>
> http://localhost:8529/_db/mydb/_api/version

This information can be found in the documentation:

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/http/databases/

If no database is specified in the request URL, the `_system` database is used by default.

To create a hash index on collection `NodesElectric` in your database `production` the following URL has to be used:

```
http://localhost:8529/_db/production/_api/index?collection=NodesElectric
```